# Is Next.JS API needed when I using React Context?

Tags: next.js, react-context

I have getProduct function to fetch products from mongoDB, then I create Next API endpoint under api folder. Then I decide to use React Context to passed products data to entire app, should I fetch the data via API or directly using getProduct function in Context file ? What benefit of using API in this situation?